# A warm welcome for the wrong group of gunslingers?

Tags: the-dark-tower

I have been plowing through the Dark Tower audiobooks in preparation for 'The Wind Through the Keyhole' and I noticed the following:

> At the end of 'Wolves of the Calla,' Black Thirteen sends Jake and Callahan through the door that was meant for Roland and Eddie, and vice versa.  This results with Roland/Eddie showing up in Maine with Jack Andolini as a welcome party.

My question is: **how did Mia know that the switch would occur?**

> She notified Richard Sayre about where they'd ended up, but how could she have known?  If I understood right, the 'welcome party' was expecting Roland and Eddie, but that was the door Jake and Callahan had planned on going through...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that Mia could have tampered with the door prior to going through to engineer such an event?  She doesn't want to tangle with Roland (a very powerful Gunslinger) or Eddie (his love for Susannah makes him equally terrifying I imagine) so she sends them to Maine and alerts Balazar via whatever means, expecting Jake and Oy (she may not have known that Callahan would join them) to follow her.  She figures that there is little a 12 year old and a bumbler can do to her.

In this way she keeps The Really Bad Man away, while she has the Chap, while at the same time offering him, and Eddie, up to the authorities.  The doors are magic, and Mia has something of a background in the mystical.  I would not put it past her to be conniving and clever enough to do that.